# rails: how to open the ENV in binary mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

One day my application declared all passwords invalid.

After tedious search the problem was found: a cipher initialization vector (just a bunch of random bits) is given to the application via ENV. And rails had decided to convert this string (which is arbitrary binary data) to UTF-8.

I'm doing basically this, before server start:

```
ENV["RAILS_ACC_VEC"] = "\xB3n%-\x9E^\xE1\x93 \x17\xEER\x1B\n\x84S"
Rack::Server.start( ...
```

and later

```
  if Rails.env != "production"
    salt = "dummy"
  else
    salt = ENV["RAILS_ACC_VEC"]
  end
```

The bitstring should be 128 bit long. But it happened to be 176 bit long and contained valid UTF-8. (Obviousely, the cipher routines did utterly fail with that.)

The application currently runs on Rails 4.2.8 and ruby 2.4, and with default encoding.

The reason for the problem could be found: usually the application is started with the server or from deploy, with no locale in the environment. This time it was started from a console, and that console happened to be set to ISO 8859.

The consequence is also clear: one needs to take care that the application is always started with a definite locale in the ENV - either `LC_CTYPE=C` (equivalent to no locale), or -maybe better- UTF-8 (in case the application has default `config.encoding`).

What I am now trying to figure out, is, when and why does ruby/rails do such things? 
I know that transcoding may happen with an IO object, but there the intended charset can be specified when opening.

It may make some sense, if the system seems to run in ISO 8859, and rails itself runs with UTF-8, that the ENV, when moved from outside to inside, may need transcoding. But that holds true only if language is concerned, and not all ENV content might be language.

So, how is the ENV opened in binary mode?

The more ambitioned question then is, are there more evil dangers of such kind around with the Encoding feature?

Answer (score 2):

You should not store binary data in the system environment. The operating system is not designed to store binary data in its environment. I don't believe any provide that feature. All environment variables should be text. Maybe an OS can store binary data in the environment, but I don't believe that is a standard. I doubt they can store a null byte (`\x00`). It is probably a security risk for operating systems, leading to buffer overflow exploits for other programs that read the environment. Try a search of 'posix env binary'.

You should store your IV as base64 encoded data whenever you store it as text.

```
ENV['IV'] = 'VGhpcyBjYW4gYmUgYmluYXJ5Lg=='
export IV=VGhpcyBjYW4gYmUgYmluYXJ5Lg== # or from the shell
...
iv = Base64.decode64 ENV['IV']
```

Comment: Nice approach, that is certainly on the safe side. Checking allowed environment values: You're right, null byte cannot be stored there; everything else is allowed: " values [...] are not restricted except that they are considered to end with a null byte"